# Trying to get Javascript music player to work on external website

Tags: javascript-framework

I was using the SCM music player for my tumblr page and a couple of other pages on the internet. But the SCM website went down. I found the player source files and loaded them onto my server. The script works fine on the website that the files are hosted on, but when I try to use the script on web pages that aren't on my server it seems that it just won't work.

I tried looking in the script file to see if there was something I could fix, but no luck. Is there something wrong with the code below?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.itsnotch.com/tumblr/SCMmusic/script.php" ><!--
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
SCMMusicPlayer.init("{'skin':'http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/SCMmusic/skins/cyber/skin.css','playback':{'autostart':'true','shuffle':'true','volume':'50'},'playlist':[{'title':'Dam-Funk','url':'http://itsnotch.com/music/10_west.mp3'}],'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':'false'}");
//--></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. For anybody who would still like to use the SCM music player.

You will have to download the files from a site (forgot which one, just google it). Then you'll have edit the script.php file.

There a line of code that reads like this.

"this.url =" and then a php method follows it. Erase the  and everything between it and replace it with the actual container.php url path.

ANd it should work